# Shopify Theme Help - Editing "Add to Cart" button

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm trying to edit the "Add to Cart" button text to say "Pre-Order".

I started by following the instructions here:
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/products/add-to-cart/allow-pre-orders?utm_campaign=Gurus&utm_medium=link&utm_source=gurucopy#sectioned-themes

Then I got stuck at Step 10 of "Creating a pre-order product page template" section.

I've asked the theme's author for help, and they said it can be done by editing the below line of code....

```
<button class="productForm-submit js-productForm-submit {% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %}add-to-cart-btn-style{% endif %}" type="submit" name="checkout" data-handle="{{product.handle}}">{{ 'products.form.submit' | t }}</button>
```

But I'm not sure where to find the actual button text to edit. Other than that, they haven't been able to provide any more help.

Any help?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line `{{ 'products.form.submit' | t }}` with `Pre-Order`. This is if you like the text to be static.

It will be better to go to your admin panel `/admin` then in `Online Store -> Themes` click the `Action` button/dropdown and click `Edit Languages`. You will be redirect to the language page where you must click the `Products` and there must be a line with the heading `Form` and somewhere below it you will have a label called "Submit" where you can edit the text dynamically.